# Change a function to component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new at React and I created a project where I'm using two functions which are defined inside the main component. I was wondering how I could change the functions into components.

Those are the two functions I'm trying to change into components:

```
function AnswerFrame(props) {

  var selectedNumbers = props.selectedNumbers.map(function(i) {
    return <span onClick={props.unselectNumber.bind(null, i)}>{i}</span>;
  });

  return (
    <div id="answer-frame">
      <div className="well">{selectedNumbers}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function NumbersFrame(props) {
  var selectNumber = props.selectNumber,
    usedNumbers = props.usedNumbers,
    selectedNumbers = props.selectedNumbers,
    numbers = [],
    className = null;

  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    className = "number selected-" + (selectedNumbers.indexOf(i) >= 0);
    className += " used-" + (usedNumbers.indexOf(i) >= 0);
    numbers.push(
      <div className={className} onClick={selectNumber.bind(null, i)}>
        {i}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div id="numbers-frame">
      <div className="well">{numbers}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've changed the both to components following the structure of one of the answers

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; import '../App.css';

export default class NumbersFrame extends Component{

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

render(){


var selectNumber = this.props.selectNumber,
    usedNumbers = this.props.usedNumbers,
    selectedNumbers =  this.props.selectedNumbers,
    numbers = [], 
    className = null;

  for (var i=1; i <=9; i++){
    className = "number selected-" + (selectedNumbers.indexOf(i)>=0);
    className += " used-" + (usedNumbers.indexOf(i)>=0);
    numbers.push(
        <div className={className} onClick={selectNumber.bind(null, i)}>
          {i}
        </div>
      )
     }

  return(
      <div id="numbers-frame">
        <div className="well">
          {numbers}
        </div>
      </div>
      );
 }
```

}

```
class AnswerFrame extends React {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
  }

  render() {

  var selectedNumbers = this.props.selectedNumbers.map(function(i){
    return(
      <span onClick={this.props.unselectNumber.bind(null, i)}>
        {i}
      </span>
    )
  });

  return(
    <div id="answer-frame">
      <div className="well">
        {selectedNumbers}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

After using both Components I'm getting the following error in the AnwserFrame component:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

in the line

```
<span onClick={this.props.unselectNumber.bind(null, i)}>
```

I think it is because before I was using the function with the props as a parameter and now when I change to a component, the props are undefined.

Any idea about how I could handle that error before with the functions it was working well.

Comment: Since both the functional components doesn’t play with state so I would recommend you to keep them remain as stateless component

Comment: I'm confused. Do it the same way you did the other functions that are components.

Comment: Try logging the props from the constructor: `constructor(props) { super(props); console.log("My Component", props)}`, to see whether you get the props. Also I'm sure that you still need to pass the props like usual: `<AnswerFrame selectedNumbers={[1,2,3,4]} {/* other props you want to pass */} />`

Comment: If I change to that, I'll get the following:

My Component 
{selectedNumbers: Array(4)}
selectedNumbers: (4) [1, 2, 3, 4]
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are Components in themselves, called functional components.
If you need to convert it into class components here is a sample for one,

```
class AnswerFrame extends React.Component{
    render(){

    var selectedNumbers = this.props.selectedNumbers.map(function(i){
      return(
          <span onClick={this.props.unselectNumber.bind(null, i)}>
          {i}
          </span>
        )
    });

    return(
      <div id="answer-frame">
        <div className="well">
          {selectedNumbers}
        </div>
      </div>
      );

}
```